# Kendo UI TreeView selectable root

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Is there a hack in kendo ui treeview so when the user click the root node it will trigger select method, as with the other branch node.

Currently there is no options that I can find for this behaviour, and the select method only triggered for the branches.

```
    var areaDropDownTreeView = $(tvElement).kendoExtDropDownTreeView({
        treeview: {
            template: kendo.template($(tvTemplate).html()),
            dataSource: dataSource
        }
    }).data("kendoExtDropDownTreeView");

    var $dropdownRootElem = $(areaDropDownTreeView.dropDownList().element).closest("span.k-dropdown");
    var $treeviewRootElem = $(areaDropDownTreeView.treeview().element).closest("div.k-treeview");

    // Unbind default select event.
    areaDropDownTreeView.treeview().unbind("select");
    // Bind new select event.
    areaDropDownTreeView.treeview().bind("select", function (e) {
       // want to do something here for every node including the root, but the root is not triggering select, only the branches are
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by making sure you are building your TreeView correctly:

```
$("#myTreeView").kendoTreeView({ ...settings go here... } );
```

**Here is an example of selection working on all nodes of the tree:**

http://jsbin.com/edamuj/1260/edit?html,output

OnSelect **will** fire for any node in the tree, including a root node. I would guess that it has to do with the **bizzaro** way you are binding. If you want to control actions (maybe you don't always want to have onSelect do something), it might help to manage these decisions the select event function itself. **This is the recommended approach.** If you don't follow the recommend approach list in the kendo documentation - expect unexpected results.

Instead, set your event binding inside of your treeview declaration (this is a simplified example):

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    select: onSelect,
                });
            });
```

And then handle the event normally like so:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
                function onSelect(e) {
                    alert("selection event triggered");
                }
        }
```

Comment: I did built my TreeView correctly. The OnSelect actually fires for each of the node, "except" the "root". In case you don't understand what a root is, a root is the single node that starts the tree. Read more of this topic here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure

Comment: The implementation I have described above works for our applications for any node in a tree. What version of kendo are you using? You can try and disable the default behaviour of the treeview using preventDefault(), but this would imply the event is already firing. If you post a JSBin of your treeview not working - this will make it much easier to diagnose.